# How to get HashMap nested inside a HashMap

Tags: java, hashmap

I need to get HashMap which is already inside of HashMap as a value.

```
HashMap<String, HashMap<String, Product>> myOrders = new HashMap<>();
myOrders = firebaseMethods.getOrders(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid(),snapshot);
List<String> Keys = new ArrayList<>(myOrders.keySet());
HashMap<String,Product> Values = myOrders.values();
```

I've tried already .values() method but it didn't work, any ideas how I can achieve this.

Comment: How do you know that it didn't work?  So, after `myOrders = fireBaseMethods.getOrders`, what was in `myOrders`?  Did you use a debugger to look? If you didn't use a debugger, did you try printing the contents of `Keys` and the contents of `Values`?

Comment: I think you can use the `get()` method of the `HashMap` class

Comment: yeah myOrders wasn't Null, I use Log.i and it printed Myorders just fine, but the problem when I use 'HashMap<String,Product> Values = myOrders.values();' android studio show that the provided type is collection but it need to be Hashmap

Comment: @AnthonyTuccitto I need to get all of the values, can I do that with `get()` method ?

Comment: `myOrders` contains *many* HashMaps -- if you want to get a single HashMap you'll have to specify how you want to merge them.

Comment: First, You should use `get` to get `HashMap<String, Product>` from `myOrders`.

Comment: As @tgdavies commented,  `HashMap<String,Product> Values = myOrders.values();` is two dimension collection.

Answer (score 2):

You have a `HashMap` where the key is of type `String` and the value is of type `HashMap<String, Product>`.

## Example data

Let's create some example code & data to represent that. Let's use the more general `Map` interface rather than concrete `HashMap` class.

```java
record Product( int id , String name ) { }

Map < String, Map < String, Product > > myOrders =
        Map.of(
                "yesterday" ,
                Map.of(
                        "one" , new Product( 1 , "apples" ) ,
                        "two" , new Product( 2 , "bananas" )
                ) ,

                "today" ,
                Map.of(
                        "one" , new Product( 7 , "oats" ) ,
                        "two" , new Product( 42 , "quinoa" )
                )
        );
```

> myOrders.toString():
>
> {today={two=Product[id=42, name=quinoa], one=Product[id=7, name=oats]}, yesterday={two=Product[id=2, name=bananas], one=Product[id=1, name=apples]}}

## No need for `List` with `Map#keySet`

Your use of `List` & `ArrayList` is unnecessary, as [`Map#keySet`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/19/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Map.html#keySet()) returns a [`Set`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/19/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Set.html) object.

Furthermore, introducing a `List` here does not make sense, as by definition the order of keys in a `Map` or `HashMap` is *not* defined — the keys may be in any order, even appearing in different order every time you retrieve the keys.

So let's just capture the `Set`.

```java
Set < String > keySet = myOrders.keySet();
```

> keySet.toString():
>
> [today, yesterday]

## Use `Collection` with `Map#values`

In your line of code:

```
HashMap<String,Product> Values = myOrders.values();
```

… you made the mistake of expecting a single `Map` to be returned. You asked for *all* values. Each and every one of this values is a `Map`. So you will get back a bunch of maps, not a single map.

Reading the Javadoc for [`Map#values`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/19/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Map.html#values()) tells you that the method returns a [`Collection`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/19/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Collection.html). So you will get a `Collection< Map < String, Product > >`.

So let's capture that `Collection` object.

```java
Collection < Map < String, Product > > values = myOrders.values();
```

> values.toString():
>
> [{two=Product[id=2, name=bananas], one=Product[id=1, name=apples]}, {two=Product[id=42, name=quinoa], one=Product[id=7, name=oats]}]

## Access a single value for a specific key

If you are looking for the value paired with a specific key, use `Map#get` method.

```
Map < String, Product > mapForKey = myOrders.get( "yesterday" ) ;  // Returns a `Map` object, whose contents are: {two=Product[id=42, name=quinoa], one=Product[id=7, name=oats]}].
```

Answer (score 1):

Calling `.values()` will return a collection of 'values' (in your case, a collection of `HashMap`s). You can use something like:

```
List<String> keys = new ArrayList<>(myOrders.keySet());

for(String key: keys) {
    HashMap<String, Product> productMap = myOrders.get(key); // This will return the HashMap for the 'key'
    ... // processing logic goes here
```

Or better still (as suggested in the comments):

```
for(Entry<String, Map<String, Product>> entry: map.entrySet()) {
    Map<String, Product> productMap = entry.getValue();
    // processing logic here ...
```

Comment: There's no need to convert the `keySet` to a `List`.

Comment: As you are calling `get` for each key, just use `entrySet`

Comment: yeah that did the job, thank you,